# Ionic App not working in Safari Browser or Real Device (Cordova)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-ios

My Ionic app does not work in Safari browser when I run `ionic serve`, Only the first page is loaded and app reloads every time a click event is initiated.

When I build the same app for production ( `ionic cordova build ios --prod`) and open it on Xcode and run on an emulator I get the error `NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100  Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)` and app does not go past splash screen.

**Ionic info**

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.900.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.0.7
   @angular/cli                  : 9.0.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 1.5.3
   @capacitor/core : 1.5.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, browser 5.0.4, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 19 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.1
   native-run  : 1.1.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/pj/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.19.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.8
   OS                : Linux 5.4
```

Thanks